# Is there a way to @import a LESS stylesheet, based on URL?

Tags: less

In my main LESS stylesheet where I `@import` all my LESS files, I also import a helper file that just indicates some things like breakpoints, etcout ...

```
//@import url(reset.less);
@import url(variables.less);
@import url(mixins.less);
@import url(base.less);
... etc ...
@import url(mediaqueries.less);
//@import url(indicator.less);
```

... note the last `@import`.

Is there a way to only import the last file when the base URL is that of my local, so I don't have to keep commenting out that import rule before compiling?

Comment: A bit unclear... There're ways to import conditionally, but it may depend on what is exact difference between "you local" and "other case"...

Comment: What I mean is a condition like `if @base-url = local.env [ @import url(indicator.less) ]` so that the last .less file is only imported and compiled if the base URL (or similar variable) matches the pattern.

Comment: Well, no, it's impossible to get a resolved `url` of the file to compare. The's why I asking what is the difference between you local environment and the one you don't want `indicator.less` to be imported... If it's just about "development" vs. "release/production" builds the easiest pattern is not to play with any urls or any conditionals at all, but to create another less file that imports both you main one and those you need to import for development only and to use that file in your local case (while the main less file remains the main for production).

Comment: You're right - that may well be the best approach ... in retrospect: even putting that `@import` into a condition, still means updating the @base-url variable, which doesn't save me any effort. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Well, technically if it's about explicit  `@base-url` variable  (I actually thought you were thinking of some implicit entity created by Less automatically to use as condition) then you could set it via compiler options and then us it as a [mixin condition](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature) to import the file (and then just use different compile commands for different builds). Such method may have some uses depending on the development-workflow, though `@improt`s inside a mixin or a ruleset have certain limitation.